# Subclasses & overloaded methods

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclass, superclass

I have an overloaded method, each taking a subclass of `Member`

```
public void addMember(Player p) {
```

and

```
public void addMember(Supporter s) {
```

I have an `ArrayList<Member>` that I would like to loop through and for each `Member`, call the `addMember()` method passing the subclass instance.

Something like

```
for(Member m : members) {
    this.addMember(m);
}
```

But can't because I dont have a method of `addMember(Member m)`

Is there a solution that involves keeping my overloaded methods at all?

Cheers.

Comment: `public void addMember(Member  m)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you don't need two different methods you just need one method `public void addMember(Member m)`. You can assign a `subclass` instance to a `parent` class but not the opposite because `subclass` inherits the properties of `parent` class.

Remove `public void addMember(Player p)` and `public void addMember(Supporter s)`

and define a method `public void addMember(Member m)`.

Now as `Supporter`  and `Player` are subclass of `Member` reference variable of `Member` can hold them.

***N.B.:*** Use `Member m` carefully because `Member` don't have the properties of `Supporter`  and `Player` except the `overridden` ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I did know this, however in my situation I needed to differentiate and do different things to each subclass. I did that checking the `instancesof` & then running another method catered to handle that type of subclass. Hope that helps someone else with a similar problem